# SPRING batch Flatfilewriter specific model entity properties

Tags: spring, spring-batch

As part of the spring batch processer I do sent an model to the Flatfilewriter.However I do need to restrict it from writing all the properties from writing to a file and instead it should write the once I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

May I know where exactly you are facing problem.

If I understand your concern, it’s about how to select subset of columns from model. For that you and refer following example.

For example:

```
//Student.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgConstructor
public class Student {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;
}
```

While defining Job Configuration in BeanWrapperFieldExtractor you have to use only required columns to be saved.

```
//ExportToCsvFileJobConfig.java
@Configuration
public class ExportToCsvFileJobConfig {
    @Bean
    ItemWriter<Student> csvItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Student> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
 
        String exportFileHeader = "NAME;EMAIL_ADDRESS;COURSE";
        StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
        csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
 
        String exportFilePath = "/tmp/students.csv";
        csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));
 
        LineAggregator<Student> lineAggregator = createLineAggregator();
        csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
 
        return csvFileWriter;
    }
 
    private LineAggregator<Student> createLineAggregator() {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<Student> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(";");
 
        FieldExtractor<Student> fieldExtractor = createFieldExtractor();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
 
        return lineAggregator;
    }
 
    private FieldExtractor<Student> createFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Student> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames(new String[] {"name", "email", "course"});
        return extractor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it and i get

Comment: I get the following error:                                                                           
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: @user2239309 Can you please post configuration for same?